# How to select multiple images from gallery in titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-modules

Here I have the code to select image from gallery, but how can I select multiple images from gallery?

```
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    // allowEditing:true,
    mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
    success : function(e) {
        alert(e);
        ImageView.image = e.media;
        //alert('height:'+e.media.height+'width:'+e.media.height);
        lblWidth.text = 'W :'+e.media.width;
        lblHeight.text ='H :' +e.media.height;
    },
    cancel : function() {
    },
    error : function(err) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I found the module for android

[Link](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/7215#!overview)  for marketplace (Multi Image Picker) and [Link](https://github.com/railskarthi/TiMultiImagePicker)  for the source code on github (TiMultiImagePicker).
and here is the [Link](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/10415?restoreSearch=true#!overview) for iOS module.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting multiple images isn't supported either by Titanium nor native iOS.

You can try this [iOS Asset Library Access](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1291) module. However, I read that there are some issues with it.