# Import all photos from library

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am creating a photo gallery application, and I would like to import all photos from the native gallery of the device in one go.
Is there a way to access a list of all the photos?
I suppose there must be, since many applications give the option to upload all the photos to the cloud, such as Dropbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select multiple images from gallery in titanium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932349/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-titanium)

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate of the above. The above shows how to select multiple photos. The OP is asking how to query all of them, such as what Dropbox or other cloud storage services offer. The two are similar but distinctly different interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this capability is exposed by Titanium on iOS at the moment. You could show the gallery picker to the user, and let them pick the photos to be uploaded, but that doesn't sound like what you want.

It sounds like you want to use `PHPhotoLibrary` to query all of the photos, and then possibly make changes to them. You can either use [Hyperloop](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/08/hyperloop-is-here/) or [write a custom module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Quick_Start).

On Android, I believe it's device dependent, but some cursory exploration suggests the photos are stored commonly on external storage. You could use the [Titanium Filesystem APIs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem) to iterate over and find photos.